# C++ SFML 2.0 Load Image From File

Tags: c++, image, sfml

I am new to SFML and i am using SFML 2.0 i just wrote some code and its work fine but the probblem is that whaen i load the image to show on screen its give me error that

```
Failed to load image "Splashscreen.png". Reason : Unable to open file
Failed to load image "Mainmenu.png". Reason : Unable to open file
```

My code to load image from Url is

For Menu Image

```
sf::Texture menuTexture;


menuTexture.loadFromFile("Mainmenu.png");
    {
        sf::Sprite sprite(menuTexture);

        MenuItem playButton;
        playButton.rect.top = 145;
        playButton.rect.height = playButton.rect.top + 380;
        playButton.rect.left = 0;
        playButton.rect.width = playButton.rect.left + 1023; 
        playButton.menuAction = Play;

        MenuItem exitButton;
        exitButton.rect.top = 0;
        exitButton.rect.height = exitButton.rect.top + 1023;
        exitButton.rect.left = 383;
        exitButton.rect.width = exitButton.rect.left + 560; 
        exitButton.menuAction = Exit;

        menuItem.push_back(playButton);
        menuItem.push_back(exitButton);

        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();

        return GetMenuResponse(window);
    }
```

For Splash Screen Image

```
sf::Texture texture;
    if(texture.loadFromFile("Splashscreen.png") != true)
    {
        return;
    }

    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);
    renderWindow.clear();
    renderWindow.draw(sprite,sf::RenderStates::Default);
    renderWindow.display();
    sf::Event event;
        while(true)
        {
            while(renderWindow.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if(event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed 
                    || event.type == sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed
                    || event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

The image is not loading can anyone help to solve this problem.

But when i build my project and i run the same program from debug folder i mean when i run exe file images are showing up but when i run the program from Visual Studio 2010 Images are not loading And when i run the program in release mode the program is crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked that the file is in your working directory? It can be different from the output directory!

Comment: Thanks man its solve my problem i have moved the files in working directory and its worked

Comment: But the program is not running on Release mode its crash

Comment: You can have different settings for debug and release mode. So check if you've applied the changes to all configurations. I have the habbit of changing the working directories to the output directories and have all needed files there. Saves me alot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks man works perfectly fine. Can u please tell me if make folder in Visual studion Solution and copy files in that folder do i need to copy all those file in working directory too?

Comment: just like i copy the images in folder(filter) which i created in Solution explorer but i didnt copy images in Working directory. thats why imags are not shoeing up.

Comment: @HaseebKhan: Yes, I think you need to copy all files manually to the working directory but I'm not sure.